# Swing - Avoid line filling between different lines

Tags: java, swing, graphics, line, mouselistener

I'm trying to get into Swing by developing a simple drawing application in Java.

The problem is that I'm using an array of `Points` to keep track on the `mouseDragged` event, but when I release the mouse button and I begin to draw a new line they get connected (previous line's last node to the first point of the new line).

I was thinking maybe to keep track of the `Points` listened by the `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased` listeners in another `ArrayList`, to know which are the begin and end points of every line and then, when it's time to draw the lines between the points, checking if they are in the `ArrayList` and avoid drawing that line.

What is your suggested approach? How can I implement this in my code? Thank you!

```
package ccdraw;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawingArea extends JPanel implements MouseInputListener {

    private ArrayList<Point> pointList = new ArrayList<Point>();
    //private ArrayList<Point> beginEndPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();

    public DrawingArea() {
        super();
        super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        doDrawing(g);
    }

    private void doDrawing(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.5f));

        for (int i=1;i<pointList.size()-1;i++){
            // here i should check when it changes between old and new line
            // and don't draw the line between those two points!
            //if(pointList.get(i).x - pointList.get(i+1).x <= 1 &&     pointList.get(i).y - pointList.get(i+1).y <= 1)
            g2d.drawLine(pointList.get(i).x, pointList.get(i).y,     pointList.get(i+1).x, pointList.get(i+1).y);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    pointList.add(arg0.getPoint());

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(  MouseEvent arg0) {
    pointList.add(arg0.getPoint());
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
    pointList.add(arg0.getPoint());
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was thinking maybe to keep track of the Points listened by the mousePressed and mouseReleased listeners in another arraylist,

Keep an ArrayList of ArrayLists.

So every time you do a mousePressed you start an new ArrayList for the series of Points to be added by the mouseDragged event.

Then in the painting code you iterate through the two ArrayLists. This should be easier than adding exception logic for the start/end points.

Another option is to do the drawing directly to a BufferedImage, so you don't need to keep track of the Points at all. Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) which compares these two general custom painting approaches to decide which approach is best for your requirment.

Comment: Using an ArrayList<Line> was my choice, and I created another Line class that handles the points with an ArrayList<Point> .